# Counting the number of subprocesses/child processes in python

Tags: python, bash, macos

I do not have a software background so please forgive any incorrect terminology.

I want to create a loop in a python script that monitors the number of child processes created. Below is an example of the code in python:

```
for x in list:
   os.system('program --input %s &' % (x))
   while int(subprocess.check_output("echo $(pgrep -c -P$$)", shell=True)) > n-1:
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

The aim here is to run multiple jobs at the same time (there are 10,000<) without overloading the system. Jobs are run in the background and when the number of running jobs drops below a certain number (n-1), the next one begins.

The above code works when running the .py script in ubuntu, but fails to work in macOS due to the lack of the -c option for pgrep.

Using the following:

```
subprocess.check_output("pgrep -P$$ | wc -l", shell=True)
```

...does work in the mac terminal, but fails to return a correct value from within python using *os.system()*. Would there be a difference when running the code through an open python console or executing it as a script?

Is there a better (perhaps more pythonic) or smarter way to write the code to allow this loop to work on macOS **without** having to install a different version of pgrep? Perhaps using by using the *psutil* module or by running the program in it's own child thread through some sort of *popen* function, making them easier to monitor?

Thank you very much!

---

**Edits:**
Revamped code:

```
import subprocess 
import psutil
import time

def childCount():
    current_process = psutil.Process()
    children = current_process.children()
    return(len(children))

for x in range(1,11):
    subprocess.Popen(['sleep 2'], shell=True)
    print('running %s' % (str(x)))
    while childCount() > 4:
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

However, now the issue is that the script becomes hung on the 5th iteration. Perhaps the new process opened up by `subprocess.Popen` is not terminated or closed when the child (`sleep` in this case) has finished running?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `os.system()`?  The `subprocess` module is supposed to replace that interface.  The problem with `os.system()` is that it creates an extra shell process.   *psutil* is a preferable way to go rather than using other external programs.  I don't understand why you need the `echo` or the subshell on the `pgrep` output, it seems superfluous.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on using subprocess to run the command. Running the command with `subprocess.Popen` does seem to work well and perform the task I need. I can monitor the number of children with `psutil` (please see edits above). However, the executed script does seem to get stuck on the 5th instance, perhaps as the newly spawned processes don't close/terminate after the child program has completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have are a bunch of zombie child processes from the parent process (i.e. `subprocess` call) not waiting on the exit status before they terminate.

```
import subprocess 
import psutil
import time

def childCount():
    current_process = psutil.Process()
    children = current_process.children()
    return(len(children))

for x in range(1,11):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['sleep 2'], shell=True) # save the Popen instance
    print('running %s' % (str(x)))
    while childCount() > 4:
        time.sleep(0.25)
        p.communicate() # this will get the exit code
```

By getting the exit status with `Popen.communicate` you will free your zombie children.

Comment: Thank you very much for both explaining the issue and providing a solution - this works perfectly for me. I've been banging my head against the wall for a long time with this, much appreciated! Do I need to be concerned about using `shell-True`? I've read this can create major issues if used incorrectly? Obviously, the program I intend to run in the child process has multiple arguments and inputs.

Comment: @minor7 glad to be of assistance.  A `wait` system call is usually the next step when forking processes.  The return codes are most often helpful in how to proceed (or not to proceed for that matter) in the parent process.  As for using a subshell, the danger that I most often associate with that comes from when, you *know* there will be input coming from elsewhere but don't have anyway to sanitize or control it.